# Iterate through directory to build menu structure

Tags: php, directory

I need to fetch all folder names from a spcific directory and build a menu structure with the folder names using php. 
Is there a simple way to write this in php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Native RecursiveDirectoryIterator or write an own function via scandir. I recommend the RecursiveDirectoryIterator.

http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

http://php.net/manual/de/function.scandir.php

Comment: Yeah the RecursiveDirectoryIterator looks really nice but it also returns me the subdirectories which are not necessary for my project. I have used the source code from [this](http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#92233) comment.